# Getting Text on Specific line from RichTextBox

Tags: c#

How would I do something like this:

```
if(richTextBox1.Text.Contains("what"){
      int line = //get the line that this text is on
      string value = //read the text on value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you Looking for this :

```
 foreach(string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            if(line.Contains("MY_STRING"))
            {
               //my logic
              // the variable line is a string containing the your entire text in that line
            }
        }
```

Comment: Close, Maybe something like `foreach(var line in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            if(line.Contains("MY_STRING"))
            {
                  string text  = // get all text on line
            }
        }`

Comment: @MinecraftSquadFactionsPVP what else? :P

Comment: replace //my logic with something like `string value = // line.GetAllText`

Comment: oh, sorry for the confusion. Accepted as answer :P

Comment: @MinecraftSquadFactionsPVP please accept the answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

With Regular Expressions you could do it regardless of the text source:

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, $"^(?:.*?)?{word}(?:.*?)?$", RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
    //do it here
    //the line string is m.Value
}
```